# onclick anchor-link auto click element

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick

I want if someone clicks the navigation link "Mediengestaltung" (see picture) that he is scrolling to an anchor and additionally auto-click another id, in this example `#design`. Question is regarding this site: https://bm-translations.de/km.php within the navigation

I tried this, but its crashing the site:

```
<a href="https://bm-translations.de/km.php/#video" onclick="document.getElementById(&quot;design&quot;).click();location=&quot;https://bm-translations.de/km/#video&quot;">Mediengestaltung</a>
```

[image]

Comment: Remove forward slash near the hash in the URL

Comment: what do you want ? no to go to `https://bm-translations.de/km.php/#video` ??

Comment: @ThumChoonTat thankyou that was the mistake!

Answer (score 0):

`#button` id which is set to the link. `#design` id which is set to the anchor. `.carousel-selector-1` class to click on to switch to the desired slide

```
$('#button').on('click', function() {
    var anchorTag = $("#design");
    $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: anchorTag.offset().top},'slow');
    $('.carousel-selector-1').click();
    return false;
});
```